# Boolean indexing of multi-index Dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have the following:

```
                   X         Y  
A    B                          
bar  one    0.094315 -0.816244  
     three -1.316294 -0.383182  
flux six   -0.176711  0.117511  
     three -1.401581  1.471682  
foo  five   0.647646 -0.422405  
     one   -0.319071  1.598857  
     two   -0.234279  0.082658  
     two    0.423970  1.418249
```

and that I get some **boolean Series** indexing my Dataframe, e.g. `my_series = df['X'] > 0`.

I would like use this `my_series` to fill-in specific entries on column `Y`. I could certainly do:

```
df[my_series]['Y'] = 1
```

but this would write **on a view**. How can I combine boolean-based indexing with regular label indexing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `df.loc[df.X > 0, 'Y'] = 1`.